# Set a struct field with field type of a interface

Tags: reflection, go

Is there any way to set an interface field using reflect? When i tried to set it, it paniced saying that the value is non addressable.

```
type A interface{...}

func CreateA(name string) A {...}

type B struct {
   field A
   should A
   mirror A
}

// normal way of initializing
var b = B{
  field: CreateA("field"),
  should: CreateA("should"),
  mirror: CreateA("mirror"),
}

func MirrorField(b *B) {
   t := reflect.TypeOf(b)
   v := reflect.ValueOf(b)
   for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
      setTo = CreateA(t.Field(1).Name)
      fieldVal := v.Field(i)
      fieldVal.Set(reflect.ValueOf(setTo))
   }
}

// what i want is something like
var b = &B{}
MirrorField(b)
```

Comment: What would you reflect on? The above code compiles fine. What problem do you have?

Comment: One normally uses a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) for this. What are you trying to do with reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces don't have fields, they only define a method set of the value they contain. When reflecting on an interface, you can extract the value with [`Value.Elem()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem).

You also can't `Set` unexported fields. You need to capitalize the field names in your `B` type. When iterating over the fields, use [`Value.CanSet()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet) to test if they are settable. `CanSet()` will also return false is the value isn't addressable, or the value is still in an interface.

A working example of your code:
http://play.golang.org/p/Mf1HENRSny

Comment: so there is no way to set a field with interface as the type?

Comment: Sure you can. It doesn't matter what the type of the field is as long as it's a valid assignment. Your original question doesn't make sense, and may be the source of your confusion, because there's no such thing as an "interface field". Interfaces only define a method set. You need the value contained in the interface, which you can get via `Elem()` (or `reflect.Indirect()`).